# xslt template match guidance

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having issues getting my template match to work, I am trying to iterate through each of the attributes using a template match instead of an xsl:for-each statement.

Here is the xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="template.xslt"?>
<x:recording xmlns:x="http://www.example.com/xmlns/record20080320" x:ref="889002005990000" x:version="11.0">


  <x:finalized>true</x:finalized>

  <x:segment>
    <x:contenttype>mp3</x:contenttype>
    <x:starttime>2015-07-26T19:15:48.327+04:00</x:starttime>
    <x:attributes>
      <x:tag x:timestamp="2015-07-26T19:15:48.719+04:00">
        <x:attribute x:key="ref">123456</x:attribute>
      </x:tag>
      <x:tag x:timestamp="2015-07-26T19:15:48.719+04:00">
        <x:attribute x:key="genre">rock</x:attribute>
      </x:tag>
      <x:tag x:timestamp="2015-07-26T19:15:48.719+04:00">
        <x:attribute x:key="artist">Anees CK</x:attribute>
      </x:tag>
    </x:attributes>
    <x:systemtype>Windows</x:systemtype>
    <x:multipart>
      <x:primary>889002005990000</x:primary>
    </x:multipart>
    <x:duration>6</x:duration>
  </x:segment>

</x:recording>
```

And this is my template,

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:x="http://www.example.com/xmlns/record20080320" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" />
<xsl:template match="x:recording">
    <Call xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/20001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Data>
            <finalized>
                <xsl:value-of select="x:finalized"/>
            </finalized>
            <test111>
                <xsl:text>some text</xsl:text>
            </test111>
            <contenttype>
                <xsl:value-of select="x:segment/x:contenttype"/>
            </contenttype>
            <sometag>
                <xsl:value-of select="x:segment/x:attributes/x:tag/x:attribute"/>
            </sometag>

            <xsl:template match="x:attributes">
                <xsl:text>found attribute</xsl:text>        
            </xsl:template>

        </Data>
    </Call>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Templates cannot be nested. What is the result you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you intended this:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:x="http://www.example.com/xmlns/record20080320" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" />
<xsl:template match="x:recording">
    <Call xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/20001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Data>
            <finalized>
                <xsl:value-of select="x:finalized"/>
            </finalized>
            <test111>
                <xsl:text>some text</xsl:text>
            </test111>
            <contenttype>
                <xsl:value-of select="x:segment/x:contenttype"/>
            </contenttype>
            <sometag>
                <xsl:value-of select="x:segment/x:attributes/x:tag/x:attribute"/>
            </sometag>
            <xsl:apply-template select="x:attributes"/>

        </Data>
    </Call>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="x:attributes">
    <xsl:text>found attribute</xsl:text>        
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(It took me a little while to work out that when you use the term "attributes", you don't mean XML attributes, you mean elements whose name is "x:attribute").

Comment: `<attribute element="Am I an attribute value?">Or am I?</attribute>`

Comment: Thanks Michael but I have tried that and it does not work.  Ideally i want to iterate through the elements under x:attributes and then filter on certain ones such as only choose genre.

Comment: What exactly did you try and how did it fail? I wasn't trying to show you a complete solution: I was just showing you where to put the `xsl:template` declaration and the `xsl;apply-templates` declaration.